# Can the extragradient method be computed only based on proximal steps?

Tags: convex-optimization

As we know, for solving saddle point problems, the forward-backward algorithm is generally not guaranteed to converge. But the extragradient method converges [Structured Prediction via the Extragradient
Method](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~taskar/pubs/extragrad_long.pdf)

Suppose that $L(w,z)$ is a convex in $w$-concave in $z$ function. Can we express the extragradient,
\begin{align}
w^{k+1/2}&=P_{W}(w^k-\beta \bigtriangledown_w L(w^k,z^k))\cr
z^{k+1/2}&=P_{Z}(z^k+\beta \bigtriangledown_z L(w^k,z^k))\cr
w^{k+1}&=P_{W}(w^k-\beta \bigtriangledown_w L(w^{(k+1/2)},z^{(k+1/2)}))\cr
z^{k+1}&=P_{Z}(z^k+\beta \bigtriangledown_z L(w^{(k+1/2)},z^{(k+1/2)}))\cr
\end{align}
with only proximal steps? I mean without using the gradient of the function $L$.
Sorry for asking the same question on MATH.SE.

EDIT: In this paper, [Gradient Descent Only Converges to Minimizers](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v49/lee16.pdf), it is proved that proximal point algorithm does not converges to saddles. Does this mean that the answer to this question is negative?